# Javascript Как перевести массив в строку для задания данного массива?

Tags: javascript, массивы, сериализация, serialize

Дан ассоциативный массив javascript. Требуется сгенерировать строку такую, чтобы она являлась выражением этого массива. Например `toString({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4})` вернёт `"{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}"`.

Comment: Подправил квадратные скобки на фигурные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4]

Так нельзя ))) Вот так надо:

```
JSON.stringify({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4})
```